# Has the definition of last 7 day/30 day unanswered questions changed (or is a query broken?)

Tags: bug

As someone who spends a lot of time cleaning up and answering questions on a very minor tag on Stack Overflow, I have tended to keep an eye on the statistics available on the top users page [here, for example](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/cuda/topusers). The 7 day and 30 day unanswered percentages are a useful metric for how busy the tag is and how much "work" there is to do.

My understanding is that the system definition of an unanswered question is a open question without at least one upvoted answer or an accepted answer. Over the last few weeks, I have observed that the 7 day percentage on the CUDA tag has dropped perpetually to zero, and the 30 day percentage is tracking towards zero. The problem is that there are plenty of recent unanswered questions on the tag (ie. questions without an upvoted answer). Right now I count at least twenty open questions in the last 5 days wihout any sort of answer. The all time statistic looks correct, but the others don't look right.

Has something changed in the last couple of weeks or have I misunderstood how things work?

---

Edit to note as of 2014-6-18, it appears to be working again.

Comment: Same problem in some of the long tail tags I frequent.  Might have something to do with the data center switch-over this weekend.

Comment: @HansPassant: This has been happening for at least a week or two, maybe more.

Comment: FWIW, this *might* have been fixed via [this fix](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/234144/163863) for [this bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/233979/how-are-beta-site-statistics-calculated)